# Message: "CiviCRM does not have permission to write temp files" after login into back-end Joomla

Tags: joomla, upgrade, php

My host updated PHP to 5.5. last night. Now, I can't login to my Joomla back-end because of an error. It says that CiviCRM does not have permission to write temp files.

What can I do to make sure that I can login to Joomla again? I was thinking about:

a) Deleting all files in media/civicrm/templates_c  or

b) Disabling all CiviCRM folders

Any help or tips would be great.

Comment: Can u try doing option a and check if that helps

Comment: The first option helped. I'm able to login at the back-end again. Additional question, which minimum version of CiviCRM must be installed with the latest Joomla 3.4.?

Comment: Great! Your second question will get more attention if you post it separately - go on :) - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 3):

They may have changed how they're running PHP for your hosting, which could lead to your old templates_c files being unwritable to the new PHP process.

As Lobo's comment advises, removing the files and ensuring that the `templates_c` is world-writable should resolve the permission issue.

It'd be ideal if `templates_c` belongs and is writable only to the new PHP process.